# Trying to calculate the distance between two points on x and y coordinates

Tags: graphing-functions

How do you take the x and y coordinates of Variable a
and the x and y coordinates of Variable b

and then calculate the distance between them?

Comment: Using *Pythagoras* if you're using rectangular coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

If you have two points in the plane $A(x_a, y_a)$ and $B(x_b, y_b)$, the distance between them is given by:
$$d(A, B)=\sqrt{(x_a-x_b)^2+(y_a-y_b)^2}.$$
Some more detailed explanation you can find for example here: https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/distance-2-points.html